# Does Memorystore for Redis support Redis Modules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore, redisjson

Is Google cloud memory store for Redis support RedisJson, and RedisSearch modules?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Official docs](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-versions) Memorystore, currently supports Redis versions 6.x but it is not supporting RedisJson, and RedisSearch modules.

A [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/232959446) was raised to the Google team  to enable JSON Redis module support for Memorystore for Redis 6.x  and the Product Engineering Team is working on this request. At this moment, there is no ETA to this request.